# coloring tabs in rmarkdown

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

consider the following rmarkdown file:

```
---
title: "tab colors"
output: 
  html_document:
    self_contained: no
---
<style>
.nav>li>a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #990000;
}
.nav-pills>li.active>a, .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover, .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #990000;
}
</style>


#{.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}

##Tab red

Tab red

##Tab green

Tab green
```

I was able to change the color of all tabs by adding some css in the beginning.
However, I would like the second tab (tab green) to have a different color.

I experimented a little bit and tried to create a different html-class for the second section by manually adding some html tag like

```
<a_green role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-green" aria-controls="tab-green">tab green</a_green>
```

But this did not had the desired effect.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work with the `nth()` child CSS selector https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

In your case add this within the `<style>` tag:

```
.nav-pills>li:nth-child(2) {
    background: green;
 }
```

Comment: One other thing: `<a_green>` is not at all how you create a new css class. It would be something like <a class="green">. you changed the html tag, which is not correct.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, unfortunatelly the `nth()` solution is not feasible in my example since I would to only change the color of one tab (out of 10).
Thank you also for the comment about tags. I am an html beginner and was improvising :).
If you have another idea it would be awesome

Comment: so you don't want to change just the 2nd tab, but more?

Comment: yes, but it would be like the 2nd and the 7th but not the rest

Comment: Then you could change the css to: .nav-pills>li:nth-child(2), .nav-pills>li:nth-child(7) {
    background: green;
 }  .... this means: the 2nd and the 7th tab are green

Comment: yeah, but this would color the 2nd, 4th, 6th and 8th as well, won't it?

Comment: No! With the number in nth-child(number) you indicate the indices. You can read this in the documentation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190441/discussion-between-cettt-and-kbrunner).