# set rmarkdown tab colors for different sections

Tags: html, css, r, markdown, r-markdown

I want to create an html with Rmarkdown. The html should contain colored tabs.
Based on the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276670/coloring-tabs-in-rmarkdown) I tried to create a rmarkdown file, where I can set the colors of different tabs.

This is a minimal working example (markdown):

```
---
title: "tab colors"
author: "cettt"
output: 
  html_document:
  self_contained: no

---
<style>
  .nav-pills>li>a {
     color: red;
     }
  .nav-pills>li>a:hover, .nav-pills>li>a:focus, .nav-pills>li.active>a, .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover, .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus{
     color: black;
     background-color: red;
     }
  .nav-pills > li:nth-of-type(2)>a {
     color: green;
     }
  .nav-pills > li:nth-of-type(2)>a:hover, .nav-pills > li:nth-of-type(2)>a:focus, .nav-pills > li:nth-of-type(2).active>a {
     color: black;
     background-color: green;
     }
</style>

---

# {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}

## red 1
## red 2

# {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}

## green 1
## green 2
```

[image]

However, I would like the tab color of sections red1 and red2 to be in red and the tab colors of sections green1 and green2 in green.
Does anyone have a suggestion for that?

## EDIT:

Here is the relevant part of the html

```
<div id="section" class="section level1 tabset tabset-fade tabset-pills">
<h1></h1>
<div id="red-1" class="section level2">
<h2>red 1</h2>
</div>
<div id="red-2" class="section level2">
<h2>red 2</h2>
</div>
</div>
<div id="section-1" class="section level1 tabset tabset-fade tabset-pills">
<h1></h1>
<div id="green-1" class="section level2">
<h2>green 1</h2>
</div>
<div id="green-2" class="section level2">
<h2>green 2</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post the html output?  the issue is related to the order of elements in the generated DOM, i.e., `nth-of-type(2)` is not referring to what you expect.

Comment: I put the relevant part of the html inside the question.

Comment: Are you using the `#` symbol instead of the `*` symbol by mistake?  The html does not contain any `li` tags as your styles imply you expect.

Comment: As far as I know in markdown language `#` denotes the beginning of a section.
I am not sure why the `li` tag does not appear. The full html (which is quite lengthy) contains some javascript and extra css which I do not fully understand :/

Comment: yeah...there's something else going on there, because the css above will _only_ be applied to `li` tags, and obv your html above doesn't have any.  Furthermore, there's no explanation from the css as to why the colors are applied.  It's a fair assumption that the javascript is creating the `li` elements and then applying the css rules above.