# How to change tabset colors without using CSS file in RMarkdown?

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown

I have tabs (using tabset) in my Rmarkdown file. I was wondering if there was a way I could change the color of these tabs without needing to use a CSS file. Anyway, I could change this in the yaml part of my code or just wrap some html code around the tabset command to change the color of it? See below:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Rmarkdown you can use inline CSS, so it's all contained in the same .Rmd file.

```
---
title: "tab colors"
output: html_document
---

<style>
  .nav-pills>li>a:hover, .nav-pills>li>a:focus, .nav-pills>li.active>a,     .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover, .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus{
     background-color: green;
     }
</style>

# {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}

## green
```

[image]

You can also use CSS code in it's own CSS chunk, both give the same result inline, without an additional file

````
---
title: "tab colors"
output: html_document
---

```{css, echo = FALSE}
  .nav-pills>li>a:hover, .nav-pills>li>a:focus, .nav-pills>li.active>a,     .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover, .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus{
     background-color: green;
     }
```

# {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}

## green
````

[Used this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59788621/set-rmarkdown-tab-colors-for-different-sections) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276670/coloring-tabs-in-rmarkdown) in my research as they are similar questions